# Matrix Equation Inverse

Tags: matrix-equations

How can I show that if a square matrix A satisfies:
(A^2) - 4A + 3I = 0     (where “I” is the identity matrix)
then:
(A^-1) = (1/3)(4I - A)
?

Comment: Try using $AA^{-1}=I$

Comment: This video may be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVF4F74Scf8

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation as $$3I=4A-A^2=A(4I-A).$$

Comment: Oh.... thanks for the help!